# TypeScript. Завершение функции без возврата значения

Tags: typescript

Есть функция типа

```
function foo(a: number): number {
  if(a > 10) {
    return; // тут я просто хочу, чтоб функция перестала выполняться
  } else {
    return a * 2;
  }
}
```

Но компилятор говорит, что это ошибка. Поясните неофиту, как правильно это оформить. `any` совсем не хочется ставить, как тип возвращаемого значения. Весь смысл тайпскрипта теряется. То есть в первом условии я просто хочу завершить исполнение функции, а во втором вернуть число. Но что-то не сходится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае можно воспользоваться [union-типами](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types). Тогда тип возвращаемого значения можно указать в виде: `number | undefined`

```
function foo(a: number): number | undefined {
  if(a > 10) {
    return; // тут я просто хочу, чтоб функция перестала выполняться
  } else {
    return a * 2;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBDAXIsIC2ARgKYBOAlDnkWYgD6LgAmxwMYxTiA3gFCKIYwTIgB8iAIwAGcj34DEpYlBCkwAbkQB6LYkBCIIGEQPYkDyIIkD8IIAEQQHwggQRA91xIFEQa4HEQAwBpErh4EYQRIAiIAaAvCCAXCCAYiCAHCBm5oCsIJax9oAMIIDcIEmIgEwggNIg5tYpwSZ6gDIgtibyAL6IxAA2AM7EcgqKyqpIGIgAVIgATOoVvOVAA)